# Drawing in Quartz 2D by pushing a button

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm a little bit nooby in Objective-C and I just started working with Quartz 2D. My problem is very simple: I want to draw in Quartz 2D by pressing button. I don't know how I can do that because there are two different classes in my project. I used that tutorial: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_7_Graphics_Tutorial_using_Core_Graphics_and_Core_Image

Here is my code:

```
ViewController.h
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
- (IBAction)Start;
ViewController.m
- (IBAction)Start {
}
Draw2D.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface Draw2D : UIView
@end
Draw2D.m
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code
}
return self;
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGFloat components[] = {0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0};
CGColorRef color = CGColorCreate(colorspace, components);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, color);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 30, 30);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 300, 400);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);
CGColorRelease(color);
}



- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 4.0);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context,
                                 [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);
CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(60,170,200,80);
CGContextAddRect(context, rectangle);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show Draw2D view upon pressing a button, you can add draw2DView as subview of your ViewController:

```
/// ViewController
- (IBAction)Start:(UIButton *)sender
{
   [self.view addSubview:draw2DView]; 
}
```

and you should remove these lines in your Draw2D initWithFrame method

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGFloat components[] = {0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0};
CGColorRef color = CGColorCreate(colorspace, components);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, color);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 30, 30);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 300, 400);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);
CGColorRelease(color);
```

They are below `return self;` therefore will not be triggered.

Comment: How I should add Draw2D as subview?

Comment: Your Draw2D is a subclass of UIView, so it can be added as subview of another UIView. 

- (IBAction)Start:(UIButton *)sender
{
  ///First initialise your Draw2D
      Draw2D *draw2DView = [[Draw2D alloc] initWithFrame:(self.view.bounds)];
   ///Add to viewController’s view
   [self.view addSubview:draw2DView]; 
}

Comment: But Draw2D drawing appears before I push button. And when I push button view's background become black.